# Cannot check if all records have a specific values in field

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to check if a specific list of `matches` have as status: 3 and 5, so suppose I have a list of `matches` like this:

```
id | round_id | status 
 1      28        3
 2      28        3 
 3      28        5
 4      28        5
```

the query result should return `true` because all the `matches` available have as status `3` or `5`. I wrote this query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `status`) FROM `match` WHERE round_id = 28 AND (`status` = 3 OR`status` = 5)) = 1 AS result
```

but this  will return `0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
select ( count(*) = sum(status in (3, 5)) ) as flag_3_5
from matches
where round_id = 28;
```

You can do this for all rounds by using `group by round_id`.

MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context, with true being "1" and false being "0".  So, `sum(status in (3, 5))` counts the number of rows with these two statuses.  The comparison checks to see if these are all rows.

Comment: this working, but could you explain this a little? Why you used SUM? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` :

```
select distinct m.round_id, (case when exists (select 1 
                                               from match m1 
                                               where m1.round_id = m.round_id and 
                                                     m1.status in (3,5)
                                               ) 
                                  then 'true' else 'false' 
                             end) as result
from match m
where round_id = 28;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select round_id from matches
where status in (3, 5)
group by round_id
having count(distinct status) > 1
```